# NodeJS Mounting a Middleware

Tags: node.js, middleware

I am exactly not sure what would happen in this case. Any info would be useful.

```
import {middleware} from "package";

var app = new express();
app.use('/api/route1',  middleware);
app.use('api/route2', middleware)
```

Would the above mount two different instance of the middleware or would it be the same instance.
essentially I want to load two different config  based on the route and work with it. 
Or would I have to import another instance of the package and work with like so

```
import {middleware} from "package";
import {middleware1} from "package";

var app = new express();
app.use('/api/route1',  middleware);
app.use('api/route2', middleware1)
```

thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the above mount two different instance of the middleware or would it be the same instance.

Yes, it would be the same instance.

> I want to load two different config based on the route and work with it.

In the middleware function, you could access the `Route` info from `req.route`, the code will look something like below

```
// package.js
function middleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.route);

    if(req.route.path == "/api/route1") {
        // load config1, then do something
    } else if(req.route.path == "/api/route2") {
        // load config2, then do something
    }

    next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the middleware in this case is the router that is being exported from the package. so based on the route it would load a specific config file one time and connect to backend system driven for various operations. So would the 2nd approach of importing two instances of the middleware. The said piece of code of checking the route will be there.